# Java compiling error missing return statement . Need clarification

Tags: java, string, sorting, compilation

So I am having trouble finishing this program off. The program is supposed to take any string you enter into it and sort the letter back into alphabetical order. I think my logic is good enough, but the return statement error that I am getting is a bit odd. 
There has to be something that I am forgetting.

The error I am getting is (will be directly below this) :

Sorting.Java :26: error: missing return statement
                                       }
                                       ^

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorting {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
    String s = keyboard.nextLine();
  }

  static String sort(String s) {
    char[] content = s.toCharArray();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(content);
    String sorted = new String(content);
    System.out.println(content);
    return char content; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: The return statement I have there now wasnt working so I removed it.

Comment: Please update the code to reflect these changes. You can't return a `char` when a `String` was expected.

Comment: It works with the edit, but wont show the sorted output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning a String.  You can convert a `char[]` to a `String` via one of the constructors for `String`, ie `return new String(content)`; however, you already have a `String` in `sorted`, so all you need to do is:

```
return sorted;
```

Additionally this won't do anything because you aren't ever calling the sort method on the inputted string.
Add `sort(s);` to the end of your main method.

Comment: He said he removed the return statement

Comment: Suggesting to make another string object makes no sense.

Comment: @SteveP. its to demonstrate the idea that if he marked the return type as a string it has to be a string.

Comment: @NeilLocketz I edited your post a bit.  Feel free to change it if it doesn't look as good to you.

Comment: @SteveP. This is exactly what i was going for, thanks. I've never been one to communicate with words LOL.

Comment: Ok it worked but now i have a new dilemma. My program wont show the sorted output

Comment: I enter in the string, and then nothing else shows up afterwards. Meaning there is no sorted output

Comment: Edited it, should tell you what you need now

Comment: Ok thanks, it works great now. Will make sure to accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
return char content;
```

should be

```
return sorted
```

Your return method expects a `String` whereas `char content` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your return isn't valid

```
return char content;
```

You're redeclaring the variable `content`, this time as a `char` not a `char[]` (which isn't valid) within a return statement (which also isn't valid). You've said you will return a `String` so you should return one. For example

```
return sorted;
```